# Why does AutoMapping from Fluent's NHibernate ignore an enum type?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, .net-4.6

I have the following enumeration type:

```
public enum EnumType
{
    E1,
    E2
}
```

used in the following class:

```
public class X
{
    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }

    public virtual EnumType EnumProperty { get; set; }

    public virtual string S { get; set; }
}
```

I want to persist instances of this type in a database using NHibernate. And to avoid writing boilerplate code, I'm trying to use auto mapping feature as follows:

```
private ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    var mappings = AutoMap
        .AssemblyOf<Domain.X>(new MyAutoMappingConfiguration());

    this.NHibernateConfiguration = Fluently
        .Configure()
        .Database(FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(
                b => b.FromConnectionStringWithKey("x")))
        .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(mappings))
        .BuildConfiguration();

    return this.NHibernateConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

where `MyAutoMappingConfiguration` looks like this:

```
public class MyAutoMappingConfiguration: FluentNHibernate.Automapping.DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
    {
        return type.Namespace == "Domain";
    }

    public override bool IsComponent(Type type)
    {
        return type.Name == "EnumType";
    }
}
```

When I use the schema generated from this configuration to create the database:

```
new SchemaExport(this.sessionProvider.NHibernateConfiguration)
    .Execute(true, true, false);
```

the following script is being generated and executed:

```sql
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[X]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) drop table [X]

create table [X] (
    Id INT not null,
   S NVARCHAR(255) null,
   primary key (Id)
)
```

Why is the property `EnumProperty` ignored?

When I add an explicit mapping for `X`, or (what seems equivalent) an override for auto-mapping like this:

```
var mappings = AutoMap
    .AssemblyOf<Domain.X>(new MyAutoMappingConfiguration())
    .Override<Domain.X>(m =>
    {
        m.Table("X");
        m.Id(x => x.Id);
        m.Map(x => x.EnumProperty);     // this works
        m.Map(x => x.S);
    });
```

the script is generated correctly:

```sql
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[X]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) drop table [X]

create table [X] (
    Id INT not null,
   EnumProperty NVARCHAR(255) null,
   S NVARCHAR(255) null,
   primary key (Id)
)
```

This shows that there seems to be nothing wrong with NHibernate's ability to map the presented enum correctly. Why can't auto-mapping cope with this?

---

When I add the following method to `MyAutoMappingConfiguration`:

```
public override bool ShouldMap(Member member)
{
    var result = base.ShouldMap(member);
    return result;
}
```

and place the breakpoint, the `result` is `true` for the `EnumProperty` member, which somehow gets ignored later.

Comment: For some reasons, seems to be disabled by default when using automapping. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fluent-nhibernate/NJo0FiWXEwY

Comment: @Najera Please see my comment under ]DeJaVo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34714996/2642204).

Comment: When the mehod is executed is empty, but the delegate is being executed? If yes, your property is evaluated?

Comment: @Najera Can't tell, because the interface has changed. I'm not receiving `IProperty target` but `IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria`, which is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience enums are mapped out of the box, nothing extra to do at all (no custom types or components).

So, there are two problems:

- `IsComponent` shouldn't indicate that the enum in question is a component:

  ```
  public override bool IsComponent(Type type)
  {
      return base.IsComponent(type);
  }
  ```

  (or just remove the implementation at all)
- `ShouldMap` shouldn't indicate that the enum needs to be mapped explicitly. It will be mapped anyway, because it's a property. So, for example:

  ```
  public override bool ShouldMap(Member member)
  {
      return base.ShouldMap(member) && member.CanWrite &&
             !member.MemberInfo.IsDefined(typeof(NotMappedAttribute), false);
  }
  ```

  In your case, if the enum is in the same namespace you should do:

  ```
  public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
  {
      return type.Namespace == "Domain"
          && !type.IsEnum;
  }
  ```

  (which is a bit counter-intuitive)

Comment: Its unclear what you want me to do. You do need to map the Enum, so why would you put `!type.IsEnum` ? Are you talking member or type 'ShouldMap'? Feel free to edit the answer anyway you want.

Comment: Yes, "map" should be used only in the context of whole entities, not their properties - that was the main problem with my approach. I've edited your answer to explain that - please fix it, if you feel it's not clear enough. Thanks again!